# Knife cut through not working

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender 3.2 and I'm trying to use the knife cut through feature but it doesn't seem to work as expected or I might be doing something wrong.
When I try to do a cut through, I press the K shortkey then I press the Z to activate the cut through. What I would expect to happen is that I can make a line on a mesh, and the cut through would go through the obscured meshes, what I get instead is this blue line which locks my vertex choices around this line. Any ideas what's going on please?

[image]

Comment: Z was the former shortcut to cut through, now it's C as Jachym says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Z</kbd> is a shortcut for locking to the Z axis.
To cut through, the shortcut is <kbd>C</kbd>

All shortcuts are live updated on the bottom status bar ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, seems the documentation is outdated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled Cut Through (`C` in Blender 3+) and it's still not cutting through all faces, it's probably because there's a second toggle called "Occlude Geometry" in tool properties (open with `N`). Try un-ticking it. Not sure how the two interact but it helped with my mesh.

[image]